# Why in the below sentence dative "dem" is used instead of nominative "der"?

Tags: dative

In the below sentence, why is the dative "dem" is used instead of the nominative "der"?

> Gespräche zwischen dem Meister und dem Schüler sind ernst.

Answer (score 10):

Because *zwischen* is a preposition which takes a dative:

> [2] *mit Dativ*: Teil der genannten Gruppe oder Menge seiend

(source: [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zwischen))

Comment: Maybe this helps: If you you can ask "wem oder was?", it's Dativ. This is how native speaker children learn it at elementary school (at least I did about 25 years ago).

Comment: _@Glorfindel_ Oh, I didn't notice so far that you're also such well versed in German. Tausendsassa :)

Comment: @Connum I'm afraid, that doesn't help at all. If you don't know what case to ask for, you don't know the right interrogative. It works only for native speakers.

Comment: @Connum The question in dative is only _Wem?_ In accusative it is _Wen oder was?_ Nevertheless, this does usually not help, as Olafant already objected.

Comment: "wem oder was habe ich einen Schaden zugefügt? Dem Auto"

Comment: *Zwischen* can also take the accusative. But not in that meaning.

Comment: @Connum "Was habe ich einen Schaden zugefügt?" sounds weird, doesn't it? ;)

Comment: @Annatar "Wem habe ich einen Schaden zugefügt?" also sounds weird though, when you know that it's a car. I think there's just no correct way to ask for inanimates in the Dative.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you think that nominative should be used here.

But I think that your problem is that "*Gespräche zwischen dem Meister und dem Schüler*" is the subject of the sentence and subjects of sentences are in nominative.

This is correct; the entire expression "*Gespräche zwischen dem Meister und dem Schüler*" must be in nominative case.

However, a complete expression containing a preposition is **not** put into nominative case by putting all substantives into nominative case!

Instead, the substantives that are used together with a preposition do not change their case when changing the case of the entire expression. Their cases are depending on the preposition.

Another example:

Just like the preposition "*zwischen*" the preposition "*auf*" requires dative case.

Now we change the case of the dative expression "*Dem Turm auf dem Berg*" to the three other cases:

> Nominative: Der Turm auf de**m** Berg  (*and not*: Der Turm auf de**r** Berg)
>   Genitive: Des Turmes auf de**m** Berg  (*and not*: Des Turmes auf de**s** Berg**es**)
>   Accusative: Den Turm auf de**m** Berg  (*and not*: Den Turm auf de**n** Berg)

As you can see, the case of the substantive "*Turm*" changes when we change the case of the entire expression; however, the case of the substantive "*Berg*" remains dative because the preposition "*auf*" requires dative.

(Note that there are also prepositions requiring accusative. Using such a preposition the word "*Berg*" would always be in accusative.)

---

Indeed, I doubt that cases are a property of whole expressions; cases seem to be a property of single words only.

If this should be true, the expression "*der Turm auf dem Berg*" does not even have a case, but only the two words "*der Turm*" and "*dem Berg*" have cases.